# Memory Leak with Swift String Optional Binding

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I am new to debugging memory leaks, but I ran 'Leaks' on my application and here is a screenshot of what is going on: [image]

Most of the leaks are coming from this function. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is occurring, or how to solve it?

I'm using Xcode 6.3 with swift 1.2

**Update**
I changed my code function hasAddress() to the following and it got rid of the leak:

```
func hasAddress() -> String? { 
    if let address = self.address, city = self.staticCity, state = self.state, zip = self.zip where city != "" && state != "" && zip != "" {
       return address + "\n" + city + ", " + state + " " + zip
    } else {
       return nil
    }
}
```

Anyone know as to **why?** this fixes it.

Comment: can you provide an example of output ?

Comment: Of what the function would return as a string?